# How to place a UISwitch in an UITableViewCell accessoryView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I would like to place an `UISwitch` in a `accessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell`, the problem is that if I try to place it right in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` func it works and the UISwitch is correctly created and displayed at the right of the UITableViewCell, instead if I create it outside of the func it won't work. I need to create it outsite of the fun because I need to check the status of the UISwitch in some other func and execute code accordingly.

I explain better what I mean for "*outside*": with `Objective-C` you have `@property(ies)` that lets you access objects from everywhere inside the current class file, can we achieve the same thing in `Swift`?

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ConfigurationViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    weak var useAuthenticationSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.textLabel!.text = "Use Authentication"
                cell.accessoryView = useAuthenticationSwitch
            }
        } else {

        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

If, instead of:

```
cell.accessoryView = useAuthenticationSwitch
```

I use:

```
cell.accessoryView = UISwitch()
```

It works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not creating the `UISwitch`.

Replace this:

```
weak var useAuthenticationSwitch: UISwitch!
```

With this:

```
var useAuthenticationSwitch = UISwitch()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You have not unwrapped the UISwitch and hence useAuthenticationSwitch will be of type UISwitch? and not UISwitch . Instead add one more extra code in your view didLoad and let all the other code be as it is

```
func viewDidLoad() {
   useAuthenticationSwitch = UISwitch() 
}
```

Now use it wherever you want!

Comment: `useAuthenticationSwitch` is declared `weak`. So I'm afraid the `UISwitch` is immediately lost after being created here.

Comment: Nothing wrong in weak because the its in the same ViewController and the information is not lost unless the user makes a segue to another viewController

Comment: When you write `useAuthenticationSwitch = UISwitch()` the reference count of the `UISwitch` object is `0`. This means ARC does delete the object **immediately after** the line is executed. This happens because `useAuthenticationSwitch`  is declared  `weak`. You can easily test this in a playground.